# FFMPEG Android - passing bytebuffer to ffmpeg

Tags: android, audio-streaming, aac, internet-radio

I'm trying my hands on ffmpeg and am stuck on how I pass the
bytebuffer to the FFmpeg method `avcodec_decode_audio3`.

In the JNI code I'm able to access the bytebuffer through `GetDirectBufferAddress` which gives me an object of the type jbyte. How do I pass this to the `avcodec_decode_audio3` method of ffmpeg?

The method declaration for is `avcodec_decode_audio3` is

```
avcodec_decode_audio3(AVCodecContext *avctx, int16_t *samples, int
*frame_size_ptr, AVPacket *avpkt)
```

Has anyone done this before.

Can someone throw some light on this? If someone can give me a snippet of how this is done it would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have started a simple project where I use ffmpeg for decoding. I have already managed to compile ffmpeg, get stream, decode and return pcm data to AudioTrack in Java. The only problem is that I get only noize back, but I'm working on it. Check it here https://github.com/mikebevz/AFPlayer

Answer (score 0):

Dont take it as type jbyte , rather take  the value into unsigned char *pBuffer 
char *pBuffer = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env,buf);
you need to typecast it to type of int16_t *samples 
then pass it to avcodec_decode_audio3(..... .pBuffer....);

and here the copying is done : 
memcpy(samples, frame.extended_data[0], plane_size);